# How does this if, while works?

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this line on a Wordpress template and I'm not sure about how it works. Anyone with any ideas?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Note: I'm not wondering about the methods. My question is about the syntax.

```
<?php if(conditional) : while(conditional) : method; ?>
```

Comment: This looks like a good explanation: http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/the-wordpress-loop-explained-for-beginners

Comment: I figure it should be read as if condition, while condition execute method. Is this right?

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I just want to be sure, but it seems like I was right after all. ;)

Comment: yes it means: if any post_exists then while(every post) do something with this instance of post (mostly printing out)

Comment: Also, PHP alternative syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 4):

That code as such is invalid, this is just the *beginning* of the [alternative control structure syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). The full syntax must include the respective `end` blocks:

```
if (/* .. */) :
    while (/* .. */) :
        /* .. */;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

You *can* write all that on one line, as the author did, instead of indenting it. Whether that makes it more readable or not is a matter of opinion; I'd say it does not improve readability at all. But then, Wordpress is not exactly a great example of great PHP practices (IMO).

Answer (score -1):

This block of code is a part of wordpress called 'the loop' ([more info here](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)). This is where wordpress loops through posts and displays them on the page